# Compose: Issue with Layout Direction

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to apply localization to my Compose app to add "ar" locale.
However, I am experiencing strange behavior regarding **Layout Direction** switch between LTR and RTL.

### What I am experiencing:

1. If App starts in "ar", layout is set RTL as expected.
2. When I switch to "en" and recreate the Activity, the app switches layout to LTR and then quickly reverts back to RTL (In a flicker).
3. On the other hand, if App starts in "en", layout is set LTR as expected.
4. When I switch to "ar" and recreate the Activity, the app switches layout to RTL and then quickly reverts back to LTR (In a flicker).
5. In conclusion, app keeps reverting to the initial layout-direction it started with. wether it is RTL or LTR.

- What I can see is that **MyAppTheme** recomposes twice when switching to a new Locale other than the initial one. First time it sets layout correctly, then recomposes again and reverts the layout back to the initial state again.

### Here is my code...

**[1] AuthenticationActivity**

```
class AuthenticationActivity : BaseActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            navController = rememberNavController()

            MyAppTheme {
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Graph.AUTH) {
                    authNavGraph(navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[2] BaseActivity**

```
open class BaseActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun attachBaseContext(baseContext: Context) {
        val initialLocale = Locale(prefs.getValue(Preference.LANGUAGE_KEY, "ar"))

        super.attachBaseContext(AppContextWrapper.wrap(baseContext, initialLocale))
    }
}
```

**[3] authNavGraph**

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.authNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    navigation(
        route = Graph.AUTH,
        startDestination = AuthScreens.LanguageSelect.route
    ) {
        composable(route = AuthScreens.LanguageSelect.route) {
            LanguageSelectScreen(navController)
        }
        composable(route = AuthScreens.Login.route) {
            LoginScreen(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

**[4] AppContextWrapper**

```
class AppContextWrapper(base: Context?) : ContextWrapper(base) {

    companion object {
        fun wrap(context: Context, newLocale: Locale?): AppContextWrapper {
            val res = context.resources
            val configuration = res.configuration

            return if (BuildUtils.isAtLeast24Api()) {
                configuration.setLocale(newLocale)
                configuration.setLayoutDirection(newLocale)

                val localeList = LocaleList(newLocale)
                LocaleList.setDefault(localeList)
                configuration.setLocales(localeList)

                AppContextWrapper(context.createConfigurationContext(configuration))

            } else if (BuildUtils.isAtLeast17Api()) {
                configuration.setLocale(newLocale)
                configuration.setLayoutDirection(newLocale)

                AppContextWrapper(context.createConfigurationContext(configuration))

            } else {
                configuration.locale = newLocale
                configuration.setLayoutDirection(newLocale)
                res.updateConfiguration(configuration, res.displayMetrics)

                AppContextWrapper(context)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[5] LanguageSelectScreen**

```
@Composable
fun LanguageSelectScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    prefs: ILocalPreferencesStorage = get()
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 45.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {

val initialLangCode = prefs.getValue(Preference.LANGUAGE_KEY, "ar")

        val (selectedOption, onOptionSelected) = remember {
            mutableStateOf(LocalizationHelper.lang(initialLangCode))
        }

            // Radio Buttons to switch between languages
            Spacer(Modifier.height(40.dp))
            LocalizationHelper.langOptions.forEach { text ->
                Column {
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(15.dp))
                    RadioButtonStroke(text, selectedOption, onOptionSelected)
                }
            }

            Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
            MainRoundedButton(text = stringResource(R.string.save)) {
                val code = LocalizationHelper.code(selectedOption)
                prefs.putValue(Preference.LANGUAGE_KEY, code)

                // Recreate Activity
                context.findActivity()?.recreate()
            }
        }
}
```

1. I am expecting the switch to work correctly without this revert.
2. Also **MyAppTheme** should not recompose twice when I switch Locale